# How to stop all ionic ngfor button from being clicked at once

Tags: javascript, ionic3, ngfor

I am experiencing some issues with the ionic app So I have a button inside the ngfor which generates a button for each card but now when I click on one button (the first one)  all the other buttons generated are clicked. how do I stop the others? If I click any only the clicked one should action the all at once.
I tried this:

```
(click)="onEvent($event)" onEvent(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

**html file**

```
 <button ion-button full  *ngFor="let b of buttonlist,let i = index" 
(click)="buttonclick(i)" >{{ b }}</button>
```

**.ts file**

```
buttonlist =[]
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

this.buttonlist = ["A","B","C","D"]
}


buttonclick(i){

if(i == 0){
console.log("Clicked A")
}
if(i == 1){
 console.log("Clicked B")
}

if(i == 2){
 console.log("Clicked C")
}
if(i == 3){
 console.log("Clicked D")
}



}
```

**Working example**

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ip2ixz)**